# Upgrading an Windows Phone 7.1 App to Windows Phone 8.1 App Certification Fails?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-7.1

We are unbale to Pass Windows App Certification Kit test (WACK Test) for windows phone 8.1 application.

It is producing below error in Debug configuration test,

The debug configuration test detected the following errors:
 1)The binary Phone.Controls.dll is built in debug mode.

Impact if not fixed:  Windows Phone Store doesn’t allow a debug version of an app.

How to fix:  Please make sure the app isn't linking to any debug versions of a framework and it is built with the release configuration— ranjit kumar  gs, Today 14:04

Comment: Er... why don't you build your project under Release configuration? :-/

Comment: I build the project in Release configration only remaining all .dll are not showing error except this.@  Abhishek

Comment: Phone.Controls.dll is built as debug, which means the DEBUG constant is (most likely) defined and the codebase isn't optimized. The solution is to get a release build of Phone.Controls.dll.  Who created Phone.Controls.dll? Go to them.

Comment: Phone.Controls.dll is came along with when the Application is created @ Will

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to just select a release build for compilation in Visual Studio as opposed to debug build. As mentioned by the error, the Windows Phone store does not accept debug builds as they are not optimized.